# I have no idea what I'm doing - Paint Methods, etc

Tags: java, swing, paint

I have been struggling with Paint methods, and paint components, and extends JFrame, and have been trying all sorts of ways to get a simple rectangle to draw. here is a class called Window:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Window extends JFrame 
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Window()
    {
        setSize(300,300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawRect(300,300,300,300);
    }
}
```

then class Main

```
public class Main {

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Window mainWindow = new Window();
            mainWindow.setBounds(100,100,300,300);
        }
}
```

The sole purpose of this program is just draw a damn rectangle. I have no idea what I could be doing wrong, and I have been trying to drawRect or drawString for several days now, to no avail. I also tried with a panel.

Answer (score 4):

Don't override `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame`, this is the quickest way to end up with a world of weird and unexpected results.

Between the frames actual surface and the use, there is a `JRootPane`, a `contentPane` and possibly a `glassPane`...

[image: RootPane]

All of these can interface/erase what you've painted in the `paint` method.

Instead, start with a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent`.  Create an instance of this and place it on an instance of a `JFrame` when you want to show it.

Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Also, beware that when painting, `0x0` is the top/left of your component, so in your example, you start painting at `300x300`, but your frame is only `300x300`, so you're actually painting of the screen

As an example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestPaint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPaint();
    }

    public TestPaint() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new PaintPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PaintPane extends JPanel {

        public PaintPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawRect(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks very much m8. I changed Window to extend JPanel and maid the paint paintComponent. Could you possibly explain the implications of using paintComponent as opposed to paint? Also, is there ever a case where you would want to extend JFrame like I did originally? Is there a way to paint without extending JPanel or JFrame?\

Comment: No, not really, seriously, it doesn't offer you any advantages that can't be achieved through other, better, means

Comment: Basically, when your component needs to be painted, it calls the `paint` method, the `paint` method then delegates (some of the) work to `paintComponent`, `paintBorder` and `paintChildren`.  Because of the way the paint API works, it's also possible for child components to be painted independently of their parent containers, which can produce some very weird issues.  So as a general rule of thumb, don't override `paint` :P

Comment: Right, so how would it be done where someone doesn't extend a JFrame or JPanel? Because to call a paintComponent method, you have to provide a graphics object. and I have not seena  possibility to define a graphics object in the main(string[] args)

Comment: *"Right, so how would it be done where someone doesn't extend a JFrame or JPanel? "* - You don't. *"I have not seena possibility to define a graphics object in the main(string[] args)"* - You can't ,or at least not one which will be rendered to the screen by itself.  You HAVE to have at least one displayed component (something attached to a native peer), which generates the `Graphics` context itself and sets up the painting process.

Comment: Typically, you start with a `JFrame`, which creates the connection to the native peer and add your component to it.  The component then connects into the paint chain. Because of the complex setup of a `JFrame`, it's generally discouraged to paint directly to it, rather instead, you use a component of some kind (like `JPanel`). This is how the API works

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You are gr8. I have one more question. I'm a still a little shaky on the infrastructure of paint and stuff- I know this might seem vague, but how would you explain the process of drawing simple graphics.

Comment: That's kind of a vague question, but you could have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details about painting works and the supporting APIs

Answer (score -1):

could you try this code

```html
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel {

   public static void main(String[] a) {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setSize(400, 400);
      f.add(new Main());
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.fillRect (5, 15, 50, 75);
   }
}
```

Comment: 1. You should avoid overriding `paint` as a general rule of thumb, in Swing, it's encouraged to override `paintComponent` instead, lots of reason, but it just solves a lot of problems; 2. You've broken the paint chain which is going to result in some seriously weird painting artificates; 3. You should be initialising your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for details. Also, your code is not JavaScript, so you shouldn't be using the snippet upmarking :P